# Excel Vlookup to a table array which has formulas returning values

Tags: arrays, excel, distinct-values

Here is my formula that is not successful in returning a valid response from the table array.

```
=IFERROR(IF(X72=27,VLOOKUP(AE72,'Rates for Medical Plans 2018'!$B$64:$C$99,2,FALSE),IF(X72=52,VLOOKUP(AE72,'Rates for Medical Plans 2018'!$B$64:$C$99,2,FALSE),)),)
```

## Main Data

[image: Main data]

## Table Array

[image: Table Array]

The table array is a series of calculations where I pull in a specific rate and calculate a one penny variance either negative or positive from the main rate.  Where I am encountering issues is that apparently the calculated values in the table array and not matching with the values in the main data located in column "AE" as shown in graphic 1.  If I hard key the values, in the table array, the formulas work (in the main data column "AD") and I am able to populate column "AD" with the correct values from the lookup.

Comment: Without really looking deep into this at all, quick guess: Did you try entering it as an array formula? (Ctrl + Shift + Enter rather than just Enter after typing formula).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this on your `Plan Cost` values in column B of `Table Array`:

```
=Round(number, 2)  //Where `number` is B3, B4, B5 etc...
```

I suspect your `Plan Cost` values are stored as (e.g.) 379.70112 which displays as `379.70`. If you `VLOOKUP` on that value you will get a fail i.e. 379.70112  does not equal 379.70.

Comment: I inserted the round statement and all is well in the Excel world.  My original cell where the initial values were input were in two decimal values but Excel must have stored those extra decimal equivalents and thus forced the equations to value it differently.   Thanks for this insight.